# Avoiding static variables in Recursions

Tags: java, reference, static, tree

**my Tree node is defined as:**

```
class Node{
int data;
Node left,right;
Node(int d)
{
    data=d;
    left=null;
    right=null;
}
}
```

I'm writing a code for constructing a double linked list`(nodes in which should be in the inorder traversal of the given tree)` from a binary tree.

my question is **how is the second method working**. I didn't get it.I wanna know its working (I coded method-2 based on some other examples)

**I've approached it in two ways:**

1)Using static variable prev (for maintaining previous node)

2)Without using it (used a class)

**method-1 is as follows:**

```
//method-1
static Node previous=null,head=null;     
Node Btree2DLL(Node n) /
{
    if(n==null)
        return n;
    Btree2DLL(n.left);
    if(previous==null)
    {
        head=n;
    }
    else
    {
        previous.right=n;
        n.left=previous;
    }
    previous=n;
    Btree2DLL(n.right);
    return head;
}
```

**method-2 is as follows:**

```
//method-2
class PreviousandHead
{
    Node HEADOFDLL,PREV;
}
Node Tree2DLL(Node n)
{
    PreviousandHead p=new PreviousandHead();
    return Btree2DLL(n,p);  
}

Node Btree2DLL(Node n,PreviousandHead p)
{   
    if(n==null)
        return n;
    Btree2DLL(n.left,p);
    if(p.PREV==null)
    {
        p.HEADOFDLL=n;
    }
    else
    {
        p.PREV.right=n;
        n.left=p.PREV;
    }
    p.PREV=n;
    Btree2DLL(n.right,p);
    return p.HEADOFDLL;
}
```

Earlier I tried to pass arguments in method-2 without creating class PreviousandHead as:

```
Node B2DLL(Node n)
{
    return Btree2DLL(n,null,null);  
}

Node Btree2DLL(Node n,Node previous,Node head)
{
if(n==null)
        return n;
    Btree2DLL(n.left,Node previous,Node head);
    if(previous==null)
    {
        head=n;
    }
    else
    {
        previous.right=n;
        n.left=previous;
    }
    previous=n;
    Btree2DLL(n.right,Node previous,Node head);
    return head;
}
```

it didn't work.I think they're creating new instances each time.

Comment: Seems the question is that why the second method works but the last method does not work. Did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: @AnarAmrastanov yeah. I wanted-ly kept that as a TITLE because some of my friends had the same doubt of how to not use the static variables in recursions but they didn't find any references. So I kept it like that so now anyone can find it out and I even highlighted my question in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the second method will work but the last method will not work. The reason is that in the last method you pass the copy of the reference to the Node (the parameters `previous` and `head`). Because of that, the caller will not see the changes of `previous` and `head` in the called method.

For more information about that, you can read the article https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java-does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html

I think your code will work if you change types of the parameters `previous` and `head` from `Node` to `AtomicReference<Node>`

```
    Node b2DLL(Node n)
    {
        return btree2DLL(n, new AtomicReference<>(), new AtomicReference<>());
    }

    Node btree2DLL(Node n, AtomicReference<Node> previous, AtomicReference<Node> head)
    {
        if(n == null)
            return n;
        btree2DLL(n.left, previous, head);
        if(previous.get() == null)
        {
            head.set(n);
        }
        else
        {
            previous.get().right = n;
            n.left = previous.get();
        }
        previous.set(n);
        btree2DLL(n.right, previous, head);
        return head.get();
}
```

In Java world, it is considered to start a method name with lowercase.